# Having problems copying an Excel range to a Word file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have looked at some VBA codes on how to copy a range from Excel and paste to a Word Document, but I can't get it to work, it creates a pdf file, but the file is corrupted.

I have the following VBA code:

```
    Sub CopyToWordAndPrintPDF()
    'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
    'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 1x.0 Object Library)
      
    'Name of the existing Word document
    Const stWordDocument As String = "C:\Users\SDETHBP\Documents\FCM\FCM Ulvetræning Øvelser\U7-U12\Word Forside\Forside fra Excel.docx"
      
    'Word objects/declared variables.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
      
    'Excel objects
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    
    'Instantiate Word and open the "Table Reports" document.
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    'Making word App Visible
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(stWordDocument)
         
    ' copy content to word
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("U7AB1").Range("A1:N24").Copy
    
    ' Pastes it to the selected Word doc template.
    wdApp.Documents.Add
    wdApp.Selection.Paste
    
    ' Sets your printer in Word to Adobe PDF and then prints the whole doc.
    wdApp.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup Printer:="Adobe PDF", DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1
    wdApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    
    'Cleaning
    Set wsCell = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = "Cleaning up..."
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

I hope someone can guide me.

##EDIT Try:##
I have tried this and that take my existing word file and fill the range from the excel sheet into it, but my watermark is then behind the "table" and I can't see it (know that I don't save as pdf yet).
So atm. it's the layout that's the problem, if I select the cells/range manual, and then copy em to the word, it's fine, I can see my watermark.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToWord()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("U7AB1").Range("A1:N24")

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next
    
    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0
  
'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate
    
'Create a New Document
  'Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
'Change: [Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add] to:
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\SDETHBP\Documents\FCM\FCM Ulvetræning Øvelser\U7-U12\Word Forside\Forside fra Excel.docx")
  
'Copy Excel Table Range
  tbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
  
EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub CopyToWordAndPrintPDF()
'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
(VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word #.0 Object Library)
      
'Name of the existing Word document
Const stWordDocument As String = "C:\Users\SDETHBP\Documents\FCM\FCM Ulvetræning Øvelser\U7-U12\Word Forside\Forside fra Excel.docx"
      
'Word objects/declared variables.
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  ' Open the Word document
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=stWordDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
         
  ' copy content to word
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("U7AB1").Range("A1:N24").Copy
    
  ' Pastes it to the selected Word template.
  With wdDoc
    .Range.Characters.Last.Paste ' or, for example: .PasteExcelTable False, False, True
    ' Saves then prints the doc.
    .SaveAs2 Filename:=Split(stWordDocument, ".doc")(0) & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

To use the workbook's name & path instead of the document's name & path for the PDF, change:

```
Split(stWordDocument, ".doc")(0)
```

to:

```
Split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xls")(0)
```

Comment: Hi Macropod
Thx. it say there is an error about ".PrintOut" and if I '-tap it out, it ask me if I want to save the changes to the word file and I don't want to do that, so if I select "Don't Save" then I get no pdf file.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen - in the answer above the pdf is created by the line that starts `.SaveAs2`. The `.PrintOut` line is unnecessary as you're not using the Acrobat printer to create the pdf. The prompt to save the document is because of the `.Quit` which closes Word. As the document is still open at that point and has unsaved changes you get the prompt.

Comment: Ahh ok.
Can see that the pdf is created, but the watermark inside the docx file is overwrited or is on a layer behind the added content from the excel sheet.
How can add the content from the excel sheet on-top of the watermark, as if I was opening the excel sheet and manual selected the range/cells from A1 to N24, copy em and pasted em into the word document.
This is the manual way, and I get it right https://i.imgur.com/WmzcBKq.png
This is the automated way, where it dont show the watermark from the word document (wrong) https://i.imgur.com/LVc2khy.png

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen - you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66407797/edit) to include the images you linked in your comment. You also need to explain how the watermark is inserted into the document. If you used Word's Insert Watermark option it will be in the header, but I suspect you haven't done that. All of this is fundamental to your question. We can't reproduce your issue or debug your code properly unless we can first recreate the exact setup.

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove PrintOut - which I thought from the OP's code was an intended outcome - and replaced that with code to close the document. We still need some explanation about the so-called watermark, though. It wouldn't ordinarily be hidden if it was a true watermark/shape in the page header.

Comment: Yes @macropod and Timothy sry. the image (watermark) was NOT an true watermark, after I made it a true Watermark, all is working 90% have a problem with the header margin pushing the added excel data 2-3cm. down from the top, but I will look into that.
THX to both of you.

Comment: @macropod about the SaveAs2, if I can't use "ThisWorkbook.Name &"  instead of "Split(stWordDocument, ".docx")(0) &" how can I then save the PDF with the worksheet name of the, sheet im working with.. in my case "U7AB1" = U7AB1.pdf?

Comment: You *can* use the workbook's name. The code I posted was just and example for you to adapt to your needs. See updated answer.